# How can I list only files that begin with "/LOG?"

Tags: esp8266, programming

Trying to list root directory of LittleFS; but only files beginging with "/LOG."

```
String str;

                     if (!LittleFS.begin())
                     {
                          Serial.println("LittleFS failed to mount !");
                     }
                     Dir dir = LittleFS.openDir("/");
                     while (dir.next())
                     {



                        if(strncmp(dir.fileName().c_str(), "/LOG", 4) == 0)
                        {

                            str += "<a href=\"";
                            str += dir.fileName();
                            str += "\">";
                            str += dir.fileName();
                            str += "</a>";
                            str += "    ";
                            str += dir.fileSize();
                            str += "<br>\r\n";
                        }
                     }

                     client.print(str);
```

If I comment out "if(strncmp(dir.fileName().c_str(), "/LOG", 4) == 0)" and associated braces; all files list.  Code with "if(strncmp(dir.fileName().c_str(), "/LOG", 4) == 0)" no files are listed.

How can I list only files that begin with "/LOG?"

William

Comment: And you're sure that the filenames *do* begin with precisely the characters `/LOG` ?

Comment: Just a sanity check here. But isn't `/` used as path separator? In my world `/` is an invalid character for file or directory names. Listed file names in directory `/` should not contain `/` then.

Comment: @Kwasmich Unless the result of dir.fileName() is the fully qualified absolute path of the file. Which is why I was asking if the filenames really do start `/LOG`

Comment: @Majenko true. Just to make sure nothing gets overlooked. `strncmp` is case-sensitive!

Comment: @Kwasmich Indeed. Not a problem if it's using 8.3 filenames, but could be a problem if the FS uses LFN.

Comment: you have a String object returned by `fileName` and you take the c-string from it to use it in strcmp? String has `startsWith`. And I guess the listed files don't start with /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a filename String to text...

```
String text = "/LOGsdfsdf";
if(text.startsWith("/LOG")){
//wee file begins with /LOG
}else{
// wops wrong file.
}
```

Look in here

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

Method url `startsWith("");`

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/startswith

Comment: FileZilla shows filename as "LOG0608.TXT."  Naming convention is "LOG + Month + Date + '.TXT'."    I could have carried the "/" over from the web server.

Comment: Need "dir.fileName()" to compare acutal filename to LOG0608.TXT.  I only want files starting with "LOG" to be displayed.

Comment: Dose dir.fileName() gives a string as "LOGXXXX.TXT" or "/LOGXXXX.TXT"

Comment: Used:  String file_name = dir.fileName();
                            
            if(file_name.startsWith("LOG"))
            {                                                                               Thanks!

Comment: gr8 glad I can help you